# How can I change the class of an element dynamically via url in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a navbar with several Links that route to sub-pages. I now want to apply a specific `className` to the element which is currently clicked/visited.

My idea was to store the new className in a const `isClicked` and apply this to the element which is clicked. I thought about checking the current path `window.location.pathname` with the name of inner html of the div in that Link for all Link elements but don't know "how to communicate with that div's content"?

```
const DashboardWrapper = () => {

    // Class Toggler for clicked element - check via url
    const isClicked = 'link-item flex items-center mb-4 rounded-md p-2 pl-4 shadow-lg bg-sx-purple text-sx-pink';

    // Run the check for isClicked
    const checkSite = () => {
        let current_site = window.location.pathname
    }

    return (
        <div className="body-wrapper w-6/6 h-screen flex">
            <div className="sidebar w-1/6 h-full bg-sx-purple-dark-soft p-4">
                <div className="sidebar-head p-4 border-b-2 border-sx-white flex flex-col">
                    <div className="user-name text-2xl text-sx-pink">Jonas</div>
                    <div className="user-name text-md text-sx-white">Example GmbH</div>
                </div>
                <div className="sidebar-body p-4">
                    <div className="link-wrapper">
                        <Link to="/dashboard/overview/">
                            <div className={isClicked}>
                                <img className="link-icon flex w-4 mr-4" src={imageLocation} alt="imageIcon"/>
                                <div className="link-text">Overview</div>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                     ...
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```js
function CustomLink({ children, to, ...props }: LinkProps) {
  let resolved = useResolvedPath(to);
  let match = useMatch({ path: resolved.pathname, end: true });

  return (
    <div>
      <Link
        style={{ textDecoration: match ? "underline" : "none" }}
        to={to}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
      </Link>
      {match && " (active)"}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: could you explain this a little? I don't understand the params in the function `function CustomLink({ children, to, ...props }: LinkProps)` where is this coming from and what do they basically hold? Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas Sure! 

So what we trying to do here is to create new React component. 

All params in this function are called props. For example, lets say we have something like this: `<CustomLink to="/your-path">Link Text</CustomLink>`

Here you can see `to` attribute, which is actually prop, and "Link Text" stands for `children`.

You can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html